# Is there a Python function to convert days in decimal into HH:MM:SS?

Tags: python, pandas, timedelta

I am trying to style a dataframe and export it into another excel sheet. I converted the reference time and time column in the dataframe to timedelta. After conversion and applying the style, the corresponding column values have changed into days in decimal.
How do I change these decimal values to `HH:MM:SS` or do I have to convert them by using the usual formulas(like multiplying it by 24 first to get the hours) or is there a way to retain the original values? For example- `0.255636574074074` gets converted to `6:08:07`.

What I have done is -

```
df['Total Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Total Time)'].astype(str))  
df_styled = df.style.applymap(lambda x: 'background-color: %s' % 'red' if x > threshold else 'background-color: %s' % 'white', subset=['Total Time'])
```

The original column values are datetime values which were changed to timedelta.

Answer (score 2):

Use parameter `unit='d'` for convert values to timedeltas:

```
a = pd.to_timedelta(0.255636574074074, unit='d')
print (a)
0 days 06:08:06.999993600
```

So in your solution:

```
df['col'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['col'], unit='d')
```

Comment: Since I can't make changes to df_styled so after saving the excel, I read the data again and then converted the coulmn to timedelta. But that removes the styling and the also the values remain as decimals.